# The JSON Value could not be converted? Blazor web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor, rest

This is my first jump into C#, Blazor, and razor pages and I am trying to make a simple
page that will show the requested JSON information in a readable form for the user.
However, I am getting an error when I run this code that says it cannot be converted?

```
public interface IJokeService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Joke>> GetJokes();
}
```

```
    public class JokeService : IJokeService
    {
        

        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

        public JokeService (HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }
        
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Joke>> GetJokes()
        {
            return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Joke[]>("/random_joke");

        }


    }
```

```
@page "/fetchjokes"
@using GettingStarted.Shared
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using GettingStarted.Client.Services
@attribute [Authorize]

<h3>FetchJokes</h3>

@if (Jokec == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>General</th>
                <th>Setup</th>
                <th>punchline</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var Jokes in Jokec)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Jokes.id</td>
                    <td>@Jokes.type</td>
                    <td>@Jokes.setup</td>
                    <td>@Jokes.punchline</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@inject IJokeService jokeService

@code

{

    
    public IEnumerable<Joke> Jokec;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        Jokec = (await jokeService.GetJokes()).ToList();



    }


}
```

If anyone could help shine some light on what I am doing wrong or enlighten me with a better way of doing this, I would greatly appreciate it.

the JSON I'm attempting to receive https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke

Comment: Please post the exact error message you are getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link yields a *single* joke.

You tell the deserialzier to expect an array of jokes.

```
public async Task<Joke> GetJokes()
{
  return  await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Joke>("/random_joke");
}
```

Comment: Correct. You need to use "/jokes/ten" for the code to work. What a weird API by the way.

Comment: Yea this helped a lot. It's an odd API, it was just something I found and decided to mess around with. Thank you!